# Zip files created with System.IO.Compression won't show directories on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, zip

I'm creating a zip file containing the following structure:

> readme.html
> my-directory\foo.txt

```
var zip = new ZipArchive(...);
zip.CreateEntryFromFile("c:\\readme.html", "readme.html");
zip.CreateEntryFromFile("c:\\foo.txt", "my-directory\\foo.txt");
```

This creates a zip file that works fine on Windows:

[image]

However, if I open the zip file on Mac, there is no `my-directory` folder. Instead, `foo.txt` has a name of `my-directory\foo.txt`:

[image]

**How can I add a directory to a zip file, such that the directory shows up in the zip on Mac?**

Comment: Right after posting this, I realized the issue is probably due to path separator differences between Mac and Windows. Checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had forgotten that directory separators are different between Windows and Mac.

The fix was creating directories by using the "/" character, which works on both Windows and Mac:

```cs
zip.CreateEntryFromFile("c:\\foo.txt", "my-directory/foo.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

For better portability, I suggest you to use the `Path` class in c# to form your paths, like this:

```
string root = @"c:\"; // different mount point if in mac

zip.CreateEntryFromFile(Path.Combine(root, "readme.html"), "readme.html");
zip.CreateEntryFromFile(Path.Combine(root, "my-directory", "foo.txt"), Path.Combine("my-directory", "foo.txt"));
```

Comment: I don't think that will help here? `Path.Combine` will produce ``\`` on Windows, which is precisely what the problem was. (Also, use `Path.Join` these days)

Comment: `Path.Combine` will use the expected separator depending on the OS it is being run. I don't see your point. The problem was not \ on Windows, was \ on Mac.

Comment: This was a zip file which was created on Windows, but opened on a Mac. The problem was that it was created on Windows using ``\`` path separators.